# Selenium error : element is not attached to the page document

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, python-multiprocessing

Am extracting data with selenium and because the algorithm has high time complexity am also using multiprocessing.

I have the function that extract data called extract_tag_data():

```
def extract_tag_data(tag,dataset_dictionary,lst):
    driver= webdriver.Chrome(driver_location)
    driver.get("link")
    for _ in range (1):
        articles=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//table[@class='table table-hover']/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[@class='media']/div[@class='media-body']/strong/a")
        for article in articles[:1]:
            article.click()
            dataset_dictionary['tag']=tag
            dataset_dictionary['article_title']= unidecode.unidecode(driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//h1[@class="title"]').text)
            dataset_dictionary['abstract']= unidecode.unidecode(driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//div[@class="abstract"]/div[1]').text)
            dataset_dictionary['authors']=(",".join([element.text for element in (driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//div[@class="authors"]/span'))]))
            dataset_dictionary['structs']=(",".join([element.text for element in (driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//div[@class="authors"]/div[@class="structs"]/div[@class="struct"]/a'))]))
            lst.append(dataset_dictionary)
            driver.back()
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//table[@class="table table-hover"]/tfoot/tr[1]/th[2]/ul/li/a/span[@class="glyphicon glyphicon-step-forward"]').click()
    driver.quit()
    return(lst)
         
    
    
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = Manager()
    dataset_dictionary=manager.dict()
    dataset_dictionary = {
    'article_title':[],
    'authors':[],
    'abstract':[],
    'structs':[],
    'tag':[]
    }
    lst=manager.list()
    tags=['neural networks','evolutionary computation']
    pool= Pool(2)
    pool.starmap(extract_tag_data, zip(tags,repeat(dataset_dictionary),repeat(lst)))
    pool.close()
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(lst)
    df.to_excel(r"C:\\Users\\dell\\Desktop\\data collection\\myDataset.xlsx",  sheet_name='Sheet1')
    print(lst)
```

the idea is abt catching a list of article 'articles[]'  in the current page and then looping through it to extract data abt each article. I tested with only the first element in the list and its working.

```
        articles=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//table[@class='table table-hover']/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[@class='media']/div[@class='media-body']/strong/a")
        for article in articles[:1]:
            article.click()
```

But when I try to loop through all the list elements It raises the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=105.0.5195.102)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x00BA78B3+2193587]
    Ordinal0 [0x00B40681+1771137]
    Ordinal0 [0x00A541A8+803240]
    Ordinal0 [0x00A56BB4+814004]
    Ordinal0 [0x00A56A72+813682]
    Ordinal0 [0x00A56D00+814336]
    Ordinal0 [0x00A83F19+999193]
    Ordinal0 [0x00A79146+954694]
    Ordinal0 [0x00A9D7AC+1103788]
    Ordinal0 [0x00A78C04+953348]
    Ordinal0 [0x00A9D9C4+1104324]
    Ordinal0 [0x00AADAE2+1170146]
    Ordinal0 [0x00A9D5C6+1103302]
    Ordinal0 [0x00A777E0+948192]
    Ordinal0 [0x00A786E6+952038]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00E50CB2+2738370]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00E421B8+2678216]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00C317AA+512954]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00C30856+509030]
    Ordinal0 [0x00B4743B+1799227]
    Ordinal0 [0x00B4BB68+1817448]
    Ordinal0 [0x00B4BC55+1817685]
    Ordinal0 [0x00B55230+1856048]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76CBFA29+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x779E7A9E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x779E7A6E+238]
```

I know its something with the DOM but am going back to the previous page after every iteration.

Answer (score 1):

driver.back()

is the main issue after each page switch regrab the elements.

```
articles=len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//table[@class='table table-hover']/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[@class='media']/div[@class='media-body']/strong/a"))
for i in range(articles):
    driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//table[@class='table table-hover']/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[@class='media']/div[@class='media-body']/strong/a")[i].click()
    dataset_dictionary['tag']=tag
    dataset_dictionary['article_title']= unidecode.unidecode(driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//h1[@class="title"]').text)
    dataset_dictionary['abstract']= unidecode.unidecode(driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//div[@class="abstract"]/div[1]').text)
    dataset_dictionary['authors']=(",".join([element.text for element in (driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//div[@class="authors"]/span'))]))
    dataset_dictionary['structs']=(",".join([element.text for element in (driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//div[@class="authors"]/div[@class="structs"]/div[@class="struct"]/a'))]))
    lst.append(dataset_dictionary)
    driver.back()
```

Comment: U right that was the issue. thanks alot sir